# Facebook connect in phonegap

Tags: facebook, cordova

I am building phonegap app for **ios and android**.In my app i want to integrate **facebook** .can i use the same code for both ios and android

Answer (score 3):

I've made this tutorial about connecting to FB for phonegap ios, but it can totally be ported over to android, in fact I've done it :)

The current facebook plugin is lacking a bit so this should help!

http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88#more-88

Comment: Why can't you use the FB integration as described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/? Is there some side-effect of Phonegap that makes it necessary to use native SDKs and the child-browser approach?

Comment: @PerQuestedAronsson you could go that route, the big difference is the way you are accessing facebook and what you're wanting to do. Essentially you are doing just this but without the actual sdk... it really all depends on your needs and how you're app is functioning.

Comment: you can do the same thing with the new inappbrowser, i've provided an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474374/facebookconnect-plugin-with-phonegap-adobe-build-not-working/16476722#16476722

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Facebook plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect). The .js file is the same but there are different native components.

Comment: when i click the login button in above plugin ,it opens the default facebook browser .can u give me steps to integrate facebook in my app?